# Application does not implement dagger.android.HasDispatchingActivityInjector

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a subclass of Application that I am conforming to HasDispatchingActivityInjector, but when I try and run my app it will crash, saying:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.testing/com.test.testing.ui.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasDispatchingActivityInjector
```

This is my Application subclass:

```
class MyApplication : Application(), HasDispatchingActivityInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)
}

override fun activityInjector(): DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> {
    return dispatchingAndroidInjector
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this error before?

Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It was because I hadn't added the android:name key with the value of my Application subclass to my manifest file.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me some headache!

Comment: Thanks , Same happens to me

Comment: `<application
        android:name=".app.AndroidApplication"`

Comment: that is not enough answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add `android:name=".MyApplication"` in your manifest under application tag.
Change the 'MyApplication' to the name of your application class